# How to unzip the U-boot image?

Tags: embedded, compression, images, u-boot

I have the U-boot image called:

> rootfs.13cy.initramfs.bzip2.uboot

I want to see what's inside of it.
Whats dumpimage cmd shows me:

```
dumpimage -l rootfs.13cy.initramfs.bzip2.uboot
Image Name:   Ramdisk Image
Created:      Sun Oct 25 00:39:27 2020
Image Type:   ARM Linux RAMDisk Image (bzip2 compressed)
Data Size:    1251896 Bytes = 1222.55 KiB = 1.19 MiB
Load Address: 00000000
Entry Point:  00000000
```

whats binwalk cmd shows me:

```
binwalk rootfs.13cy.initramfs.bzip2.uboot


DECIMAL       HEXADECIMAL     DESCRIPTION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
0             0x0             uImage header, header size: 64 bytes, 
header CRC: 0x98E059B1, created: 2020-10-24 22:39:27, image size: 1251896 bytes,
Data Address: 0x0, Entry Point: 0x0, data CRC: 0x9F716869, OS: Linux, CPU: ARM,
image type: RAMDisk Image, compression type: bzip2, image name: "Ramdisk Image"
```

So it is a RAMDisk image and seems like it is not Kernel, can I look inside of it?
any ideas, please

Comment: try 7-zip ... i found that it is able to open almost any archive

Comment: @jsotola didnt help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can uncompress the image with `bzip2`. Read `man bzip2`.

You can `mount` the uncompressed image with `mount`'s `-o loop` option, read `man mount`.

Comment: sorry for the delayed answer.  bzip2 -d --decompress says that the file is not bzip2 file. But as you can see the dumpimage sees it as bzip2, what the reason?

Comment: i can share the file it is 1.3mb